# Can you specify commit size for sqoop-export?

Tags: mysql, commit, sqoop

From Sqoop user guide:

> Sqoop uses the multi-row INSERT syntax to insert up to 100 records per statement. Every 100 statements, the current transaction within a writer task is committed, causing a commit every 10,000 rows.

But it didn't mention if you can specify a particular commit size. Hence my question is - can you specify it? anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

There are two properties that can be used to tweak this behaviour:

1. sqoop.export.records.per.statement - Number of rows that will be created for single insert statement, e.g. INSERT INTO xxx VALUES (), (), (), ...
2. export.statements.per.transaction - Number of insert statements per single transaction. e.g BEGIN; INSERT, INSERT, .... COMMIT

You can specify the properties (even both at the same time) in the HADOOP_ARGS section of the command line, for example:

```
  sqoop export -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=X --connect ...
```

You can find further description of their use in [Apache Sqoop Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029519.do).